# Unable to display information after fetching data from useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to access data from my API using Redux but when redux tool kit is showing me its an empty array. The api I've populated using postman and the post method seem to work perfectly fine, but attempting to use the get method to access that data it shows an empty array. My DB has the data though. My Data is an array of Object i.e. `[ {...} , {...} , {...} ]`

API

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:5000/info"

export const fetchInfo = () => axios.get(url);
export const createInfo = (newInfo) => axios.post(url, newInfo);
```

ACTIONS

```
import * as api from "../api/index.js";

//constants

import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE } from "../constants/actiontypes";

export const getInfo = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchInfo();
    console.log(data);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const createInfo = (info) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.createInfo(info);
    dispatch({ type: CREATE, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

REDUCER

```
import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE } from "../constants/actiontypes";

export default (infos = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL:
      return action.payload;
    case CREATE:
      return [...infos, action.payload];

    default:
      return infos;
  }
};
```

COMBINE REDUCERS

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import infos from "./info"

export default combineReducers({infos})
```

Component I'm trying to to display it in

```
import React from "react";
//redux
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
//component
import MovieDetail from "./MovieDetail"

    const MovieTitles = () => {
      const infos = useSelector((state) => state.infos);
      console.log(infos)  // shows me empty array
      return (
        <div>
        
          {infos.map((i) => (
            <MovieDetail info={i} />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default MovieTitles;
```

Is there something else I'm missing which allows to me to access the data?
thanks

Comment: Can you share what console.log the initial state looks like?

Comment: []
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
concat: ƒ concat()
constructor: ƒ Array()
copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin()
entries: ƒ entries()
every: ƒ every()
fill: ƒ fill()
filter: ƒ filter()
find: ƒ find()
findIndex: ƒ findIndex()
flat: ƒ flat()
flatMap: ƒ flatMap()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
includes: ƒ includes()
indexOf: ƒ indexOf()
join: ƒ join()
keys: ƒ keys()
lastIndexOf: ƒ lastIndexOf()
length: 0
map: ƒ map()
pop: ƒ pop()
push: ƒ push()
 it would give me something like this

Comment: And where are you calling the getInfo method?

Comment: Ah thank you, I was missing useDispatch(). for call getinfo()

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that worked